# Delimiter that may / may not span multiple lines using sed

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have pre-generated configuration files from a utility. How can I extract the parameter string which is delimited by `'),` that may or may not span multiple lines?

**`FILE1` can look like this - `PARM3` spans multiple lines:**

```
OPERAND      ID          = 'XXXX',
             ....
             PARM3       = ( 'VALUE3A',
                              ....
                             'VALUE3n'),
             PARM4       = ( 'VALUE4',
                              ....
                             'VALUE4n'),
                              ....
```

**or `FILE2` can look like this - `PARM3` does not span multiple lines:**

```
OPERAND      ID          = 'XXXX',
             ....
             PARM3       = ( 'VALUE3A'),
             PARM4       = ( 'VALUE4',
                              ....
                              'VALUE4n'),
             ....
```

For `FILE1`, the extract **is good** if the delimiter `'),` is on another line:

```
sed -n "/.* PARM3 .*/,/')\,/p" FILE1
```

Output:

```
  PARM3       = ( 'VALUE3A',
                  ....
                  'VALUE3n'),
```

For `FILE2`, the extract **does not work** if the delimiter `'),` is on the same line:

```
sed -n "/.* PARM3 .*/,/')\,/p" FILE2
```

Output:

```
        PARM3       = ( 'VALUE3A'),
        PARM4       = ( 'VALUE4',
                         ....
                        'VALUE4n'),
```

How can I fix this sed statement using sed only to handle the delimiter which may or may not be on the same line?

Comment: change `.*` after PARM3 to `.*?`

Comment: @Matt.G Sed doesn't support non-greedy matching.

Comment: You could use branches in sed. Jump when `)` is found in the same line if not continue with address range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT]more simple:

```
sed -n '/PARM3/,/)/{p;/)/q}' file
```

---

a way with sed:

```
sed -n '/PARM3/{:a;/)/{p;q};N;ba}' file
```

details:

```
/PARM3/ {     # if PARM3 is found
    :a            # define a label "a"
    /)/ {         # if ) is found
        p             # print the pattern space
        q             # quit
    }
    N             # append the next line to the pattern space
    ba            # go to label a
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `gnu-awk` command that uses a custom `RS`:

```
awk -v RS='[[:blank:]]*PARM3[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*\\([^)]*\\),[[:blank:]]*' 'RT{print RT}' file
```

For file1 it gives:

```
     PARM3       = ( 'VALUE3A',
                      ....
                     'VALUE3n'),
```

For file2 it gives:

```
    PARM3       = ( 'VALUE3A'),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU grep, you could use its `-z` option to treat the complete input as a single line:

```
$ grep -Ezo '\s+PARM3\s+=\s+\([^)]*\)' FILE2

             PARM3       = ( 'VALUE3A',
                              ....
                             'VALUE3n')
```

`-o` retains nothing but the match, and `-E` enables extended regular expressions.

The regex searches for `PARM3 =` surrounded by an arbitrary number of blanks, followed by `(` and then everything up to and including the closing `)`. To avoid greedy matching, I use `[^)]` ("not a closing parenthesis").

If you don't need the leading blanks, they can be skipped, and if you need the trailing comma, it can be added (optional, in case it's not there):

```
$ grep -Ezo 'PARM3\s+=\s+\([^)]*\),?' infile
PARM3       = ( 'VALUE3A',
                              ....
                             'VALUE3n'),
```

or to get proper alignment, but not the newline preceding the match:

```
$ grep -Ezo '[[:blank:]]*PARM3\s+=\s+\([^)]*\),?' infile
             PARM3       = ( 'VALUE3A',
                              ....
                             'VALUE3n'),
```